# Libvirt-bin failed to start Virtuelization deamon, exit-code 127 on Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am trying to install `libvirt` on Ubuntu Server 16.04. When I execute:

```
apt-get install libvirt-bin
```

Installation fails at:

```
Setting up libvirt-bin
```

With `exit code 127` and this error message:

```
Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
```

I already tried to start `libvirt` manualy with `/etc/init.d/libvirt-bin start`, as sugested in some older questions, but that simply didn't work. Also, when I try to install anything else after `libvirt-bin`, for example:

```
apt-get install vim
```

It gets stuck on:

```
Setting up libvirt-bin
```

And shows the same `libvir`t error message and than finishes the installation of the required software.

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you confirm that your server is a physical server and support VT (Virtualization Technology) ?

Comment: Yes, it is physical and i checked my bios settings and virtualization technology is enabled., but when i type  'kvm-ok', the output is :   "/dev/kvm does not exist", could it be because the libvirt-bin isn't installed successfully?

Comment: if your cpu is an intel processor, can you try `modprobe kvm_intel` and then run again `sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok` ? please also give the full output of `kvm-ok` command (edit your question to provide thoses details)

Comment: The output of sudo modprove kvm_intel is :
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-143-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module kvm_intel not found in directory /lib/modules/3.13.0-143-generic

Comment: It seems you are using a quite old kernel (default ubuntu 16.04 kernel version is 4.4 series). Is it a custom build ?

Comment: Ok, could it be because previous instaled OS was ubuntu server 14.04, 
and i remember that my home directory was same after installing ubuntu 16.04 ?

Comment: Did you made a system upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 ? or a fresh install but keeping your /home partition ?

Comment: I  did fresh install with custom partitioning.

Comment: ok, so there should be no reason you to not be using the latest kernel version. you may consider forst doing `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade` (try to run multiple times if you are getting error message)

Comment: thank you my friend, but i  reinstalled OS again and now everything is working perfect. :)